# Node.js User Authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new with nodeJs and i'm actually following a tutorial about it. 
In the tutorial, a code was used:
In a verify.js file  the following function was written:

```
exports.verifyOrdinaryUser = function (req, res, next) {
    // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
    var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];

    // decode token
    if (token) {
        // verifies secret and checks exp
        jwt.verify(token, config.secretKey, function (err, decoded) {
            if (err) {
                var err = new Error('You are not authenticated!');
                err.status = 401;
                return next(err);
            } else {
                // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
                req.decoded = decoded;
                next();
            }
        });
    } else {
        // if there is no token
        // return an error
        var err = new Error('No token provided!');
        err.status = 403;
        return next(err);
    }
};
```

and in another file, the function was called so :

```
/*****........****/
.post(verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, function(req, res, next){
    /******.......*****/
```

everything is working fine without problem. 
1- I don't understand why the function verify.verifyOrdinaryUser is not called so :

```
verify.verifyOrdinaryUser(req, res, next)
```

with his parameter (how is it possible that we call a function without his parameter .?

next , i've written a function :

```
exports.verifyAdmin = function(req, res, next){
    if(req.decoded._doc.admin == false){
        var err = new Error('You cannot access to this ressource!');
        err.status = 401;
        return next(err);
    }
    else {
        next();
    }
};
```

in the same file, to verify if a user is a admin or not, i have to call this function after the verifyOrdinaryUser  function, 
my problem is i don't know how i can make call of this function, with or without the parameters. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> 1- I don't understand why the function verify.verifyOrdinaryUser is
>   not called so : verify.verifyOrdinaryUser(req, res, next)

In simplest terms, That's because `Express` takes care of sending those parameters to the specified middleware instead of you specifying it here

And in function `verify.verifyOrdinaryUser`, The function is requesting for 3 parameters `req, res, next` and it receives those three parameters, if it requests for a parameter that doesn't exist, That parameters value will be `undefined`.

> my problem is i don't know how i can make call of this function, with
>   or without the parameters.

Just call it like

```
/*****........****/
.post(verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, verify.verifyAdmin, function(req, res, next){
    /******.......*****/
```

And in the functions code you can request for the parameters you need

```
exports.verifyAdmin = function(req, res){
    if(req.decoded._doc.admin == false){
    ...
```

Hope this gives you some sense on whats going on, You should google for Node JS Middlewares and simple tutorials based on Node JS and Express.